# Map list of functions over list of inputs

Tags: list-manipulation, map

Given a list of functions

```
{f1, f2, f3, ...}
```

and list of inputs

```
{1, 2, 3, ...}
```

I wish to produce the list

```
{f1[1], f2[2], f3[3], ...}
```

This is the list where each function in the first list is applied to the input at the corresponding index. How can I do this concisely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
funcs = {f1, f2, f3};
lst = {1, 2, 3};

MapThread[# @ #2 &, {funcs, lst}]
```

> {f1[1], f2[2], f3[3]}

Also

```
MapThread[Construct, {funcs, lst}]

Inner[Construct, funcs, lst, List]

MapThread[Compose, {funcs, lst}]

Inner[Compose, funcs, lst, List]
```

> same result